# Alias for multiple case statements in oracle

Tags: oracle, alias

Am new to this oracle concept , can anyone help with giving alias name for case statement .

```
select * from (
    Select CASE WHEN to_char(honor) = 1 then 'FIRST'
              WHEN to_char(honor) = 2 then 'SECOND'
              WHEN to_char(honor) = 3 then 'THIRD'
              WHEN to_char(honor) = 4 then 'FOURTH'
              ELSE to_char(honor) END as temp ,HORONABLE,to_char(crtd_dtt,'YYYY-MM') as "DateofHonor"
     from ld_leg_t
     where CUR_OPTLSTAT_ID not in (355,360)
     ORDER BY  to_char(crtd_dtt,'YYYY-MM') ASC )
    pivot
    (
    count(HORONABLE)
    for temp in ('FIRST','SECOND','THIRD','FOURTH')
    )
order by "DateofHonor"
```

Is there any way i can include alias name for FIRST , SECOND , THIRD and FOURTH . so that i can retrieve it using PHP  .

Comment: `CASE` expressions output a single _scalar_ value.  Then why can't you just check the value of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean *this*, then yes - see the `FOR TEMP ...` line and aliases being used.

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM (SELECT CASE
  3                    WHEN deptno = 10 THEN 'FIRST'
  4                    WHEN deptno = 20 THEN 'SECOND'
  5                    WHEN deptno = 30 THEN 'FOURTH'
  6                    ELSE '40'
  7                 END AS temp,
  8                 dname
  9            FROM dept)
 10         PIVOT (COUNT (dname) FOR temp IN ('FIRST' as A, 'SECOND' as B, 'THIRD' as C));

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          0

SQL>
```

Comment: I think the OP has some confusion on `CASE` expressions and PHP.  But, you might be right.